# Java-Finding whether given numbe is prime or not by using recursive method call

Tags: java, recursion

I had done a lot of googling about it but unable to figure out the right answer. While I am running the below code i am always getting output as "not prime even though the input is prime number like 13".
Please help me out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrimeRecurssion {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your given number is:" + prime(number,2));

    }

    public static  String prime(int x,int temp )
    {
        if(x%temp == 0)
        {
            return("not a prime");
        }
        if(x != temp-1)
        {
        return prime(x,temp+1);
        }
        else
                return("prime");
    }

}
```

Comment: check your (x != temp-1) expression.

Comment: BTW, get into the habit to give your variables names that express what they contain: instead of x and temp use names like primeCandidate and divisor. It makes your code easier to understand.

Comment: and final comment, even i answer how to fix this recursion, it's not the best way to check numbers for prime. it's not even good

Comment: Yes i know by using loops is the best way to get prime numbers.But in most of the interviews they are asking the code without loops to know my programming ability and understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if(x - 1 != temp)
{
    return prime(x,temp+1);
}
```

or

```
if(x != temp + 1)
{
    return prime(x,temp+1);
}
```

at the moment you compare `x` with `temp - 1`

eg. `x = 13, temp = 12` what leads to `13 != 12-1`
=> so `prime(13, 13)` is called, which returns with `"no prime"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
if(x != temp-1)
```

to

```
if(x != temp+1)
```

It will not cure all bugs you have, but probably fix it a bit.

Comment: as i mention - "It will not cure all bugs you have", cause it's good to think by himself about all cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String prime(int x,int temp )
    {
        if(x == 1)
        {
           return "prime";
        }
        if(x != temp)
        {
            if(x%temp == 0)
            {
                return("not a prime");
            }
            else
            {
                return prime(x,temp+1);
            }
        }
        else
                return("prime");
    }
```

This works because you only want to return prime if you have reached the number itself otherwise you will hit a not prime before that point.  Look at the code and see if you can figure out what is going on.